# replace space with underscore in Keys for a Hash

Tags: ruby, string, hash, gsub

I have a hash in which Keys have some spaces like shown below. I want to replace the space with underscores. I don't know why but the program below isn't working.

Keys:
"VoLTE QCI1 Setup Failure%"
"VoLTE QCI1 Setup Failures"
"VoLTE QCI1 Setup Attempts"

```
@@parsed_items.each_key {|key|
key.gsub(/\s/,'_')
ap key
    }
```

**Expected Output:**
"VoLTE_QCI1_Setup_Failure%"
"VoLTE_QCI1_Setup_Failures"
"VoLTE_QCI1_Setup_Attempts"

**Current Output:** 
"VoLTE QCI1 Setup Failure%"
"VoLTE QCI1 Setup Failures"
"VoLTE QCI1 Setup Attempts"

Comment: `each_key` returns the hash. What does `@@parsed_items` return after applying your code?

Comment: {
         "VoLTE QCI1 Setup Failure%" => ".239",
         "VoLTE QCI1 Setup Failures" => "15",
         "VoLTE QCI1 Setup Attempts" => "6274",
               "QCI5 Setup Failure%" => ".065",
     }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to re-key your whole hash, you might have to rebuild it:

```
@@parsed_items = Hash[
 @@parsed_items.map do |key, value|
   [ key.gsub(/\s/,'_'), value ]
 end
]
```

The `each_key` method ignores whatever your block returns, it just throws it out, so no alterations are made to the hash itself.

You could also write a helper method to de-underscore arbitrary hashes that does this as well.

Note that using `@@` class-level variables is often a sign of mixed concerns. Instance methods should not be poking around in class data, it's supposed to be considered private. If you do need access to it, expose class-level methods that give you a clean interface.

Comment: Or `@@parsed_items.map { ... }.to_h`.

Comment: Thanks. I re-Key'd my hash like @tadman suggested and it worked. Interesting!

Comment: @muistooshort That works in Ruby 2.0+, it's true. I really should use that by default.